# Getting data from PHP script using $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am just trying to get the data returned (from a php script, the script is working fine)

```
$.post(
    "http://labs.*********.com/inc/ajax/till_status.php",
     {
          id:$("#potentialID").val()
     }
).done( function (data) {
    currentTillStatus = data;
});
```

And I want it to be placed into the variabled called currentTillStatus.

Where am I going wrong?

Okay, full code is here:

```
function checkStatus() {
    var currentTillStatus = null;
    $.post(
        "http://labs.*****.com/inc/ajax/till_status.php",
        {
            id:$("#potentialID").val()
    }).done(function (data) {
        currentTillStatus = data;
    });
    console.log("Till Status: " + currentTillStatus);
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    checkStatus();  
    setInterval(checkStatus,1000);

});
```

And result:

`Till Status: null`

Comment: Does anything show up in your browser console?

Comment: Your title refers to `$.get`, but your code is using `$.post`. What is your PHP script expecting?

Comment: Well yes, I have a setInterval() to this code (function) with the line after this: `console.log("Till Status: " + currentTillStatus);` but I get `Till Status: null`

Comment: Sorry, PHP script is expecting $_REQUEST, so either.

Comment: Post an example what are you returning from your AJAX. Because this codes seems to be fine.

Comment: Is the request made from the same domain as the script?

Comment: @Boaz yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, jQuery's AJAX requests are asynchronous, so unless you've changed them to be synchronous (e.g. with `ajaxSetup()`), the `console.log()` call is made before the request is completed and the `done` callback is triggered, leaving `currentTillStatus` as `null`.

Consider moving the `console.log()` call into the `done` callback.

Comment: That was it! Thank you; I thought it must be something to do with the asynchronous part of it as that is the part I don't understand :) But thank you.

Answer (score 1):

what you can probably do is:

```
function outputStatus( currentTillStatus ){
    console.log("Till Status: " + currentTillStatus);
}

function checkStatus() {
    $.post(
        "http://labs.*****.com/inc/ajax/till_status.php",
        {
            id:$("#potentialID").val()
    }).done(function (data) {
        outputStatus( data );
    });
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    checkStatus();  
    setInterval(checkStatus,1000);

});
```

---

### Answer made before posting full source code

---

Make sure you define the `currentTillStatus` variable in the outside scope like

```
var currentTillStatus;
$.post(
    "http://labs.*********.com/inc/ajax/till_status.php",
     {
          id:$("#potentialID").val()
     }
).done( function (data) {
    currentTillStatus = data;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I have just posted the full code above, and I am doing that.

Comment: Then you won't have your value inside that variable, you console.log executes before the return of the ajax request

Comment: @Chud37 I've updated with a way you can use as a work-arround

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sorry I should have pasted the full code before hand :S

Comment: @Chud37 No problem, it happens a lot around here :)